# How can I obtain continuous results with a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.1

I am using PostgreSQL version 8.1.  I have a table of dates and tasks.  The tasks have start times and end times in the table.  The query below does not work as expected.

```
SELECT sites.abbrev,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT measurements.task
          FROM measurements
            JOIN tasks ON tasks.id = measurements.task
          WHERE measurements.ztime >= '2016-10-10'
            AND measurements.ztime <= '2016-10-15'
            AND tasks.site = sites.id
        ) ALIAS
      ) AS num_tasks,
      count(*) AS total_time
FROM sites
  JOIN tasks ON tasks.site = sites.id
  JOIN measurements
    ON (measurements.task = tasks.id
   AND measurements.ztime >= '2016-10-10'
   AND measurements.ztime <= '2016-10-15')
WHERE sites.abbrev = 'AA-10'
GROUP BY sites.id,
         sites.abbrev,
         measurements.ztime::date
ORDER BY measurements.ztime::date;
```

The results are shown below:

```
 abbrev | num_tasks | total_time 
--------+-----------+------------
 AA-10  |        62 |         36
 AA-10  |        62 |          5
 AA-10  |        62 |         58
 AA-10  |        62 |         28
 AA-10  |        62 |         17
(5 rows)
```

Each row corresponds to one 24 hour period (Ex. 2016-10-10 to 2016-10-15).  The problem is that I need `num_tasks` to show me the results for each 24 hour period, not the total number as shown.

PostgreSQL version 8.1 does not allow for dates to be used with `generate_series` and there are no windowing functions available either.

How can I modify my query so I can achieve the desired results?

Comment: Postgres 8.1 is long dead and forgotten - it's time to update to a supported and maintained version.

Comment: I am unable to update to a supported and maintained version or else I would have.  Thanks for the editing assist.

Comment: Is `ztime` a `DATE`? It would be best if you added the `CREATE TABLE` statements in the question,

Comment: If You create data structure  in SQLFiddle it will be more easy to help, but general mistake it is subquery for numtask it not depend from main query - it always calculate same data. You must use any reference to parent query - for example name parent measurement t1, subquery measurement t2 - it will be WHERE t2.date = t1.date

Comment: Does the `num_tasks` have to count all tasks, even those that do not belong to the site with `'AA-10'`?

Comment: I am unable to show the `CREATE TABLE` statements as I inherited this DB from the last DBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the subquery. Would this work?

```
SELECT sites.abbrev,
       measurements.ztime::date AS period_start,
       count(DISTINCT measurements.task) AS num_tasks,
       count(*) AS total_time
FROM sites
  JOIN tasks ON tasks.site = sites.id
  JOIN measurements
    ON (measurements.task = tasks.id
   AND measurements.ztime >= '2016-10-10'
   AND measurements.ztime < '2016-10-15')
WHERE sites.abbrev = 'AA-10'
GROUP BY sites.id,
         sites.abbrev,
         measurements.ztime::date
ORDER BY measurements.ztime::date ;
```

Comment: what if sites.abbrev != 'AA-10'?

Comment: Does the `num_tasks` have to count all tasks, even those that do not belong to the site with `'AA-10'`?

Comment: No `ypercube`, the num_tasks only has to count tasks for the corresponding site.  In this case, that would be AA-10.  I am going to try your answer above.

Comment: The solution provided by `ypercube` worked!  Thank you very much!  Issued solved.  The query is very fast too!